# Haproxy request gets timeout when doing ACL

Tags: haproxy

I created one simple application and i'm running it in 4 different containers.

I managed to proxy all the ports to the bind 9991, but when i create acl to use different backends it does'nt work, only the default back-end.

Config:

```
frontend tests
  bind *:9991

  timeout client 60s
  mode http

  acl is_servers_2 path_end /app2
  use_backend servers_2 if is_servers_2

  acl is_servers_3 path_end /app3
  use_backend servers_3 if is_servers_3

  default_backend servers_2

backend servers_2
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout server 60s
  mode http
  server server3001 127.0.0.1:3001
  server server3002 127.0.0.1:3002

backend servers_3
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout server 60s
  mode http
  server server3003 127.0.0.1:3003
  server server3004 127.0.0.1:3004
```

**haproxy version: 2.4.4**

**ubuntu: 18.04**

Comment: Add examples of URLs you try, what you expect to happen and what you get instead along with logs from haproxy for those URLs. Otherwise it's a guessing game. As for guesses, is `path_end` really what you wanted? Not `path_beg`? Are your URLs like `/login/app2` and `/login/app3` instead of `/app2/login` and `/app3/login`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was inside my server, i didn't have the correct paths that i was trying to reach via haproxy.

I Didn't know that /app2 needed to exists in my server.